# My system output is not including some values

Tags: java, project

I am touching up the code for my final project. When I run it all the output seems to be fine except some values are missing and it seems to be an error in my logic. I tried skimming through to find why some values won't show up but am struggling.

The goal of the project is to gather user input regarding computer specifications and return it. When I run the code all the text seems to match the output but my logic seems to be leaving some values out.

Specifically when I run my code the Monitor Resolution, performance score, and recommended graphics quality won't show.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //needed in order to be able to use the Scanner class to get the user's input

public class Project3_kamaal_hassan
{
   public static void main(String[] args){ // main method
        
        
        int GPU = 0; // Holds the users clockspeed of gpu in megahertz
        int CPU = 0; // Holds the users clockspeed of cpu in megahertz
        int coreCPU = 0; // Holds the amount of cores in cpu
        int choice = 0; // Holds users selection regarding monitor resolution
        int numOfComputers = 0; // asks how many computers are being interpreted
        String monitorRes = ""; // Holds resolutions for monitors   
        double performanceScore = 0; // score used to determine whether your computer can handle a game
        String graphicQuality = "";  // works with performance score   
        double multiplier =  0; // Holds the multiplier value
        String toolname = "\nComputer Hardware Graphics Quality Recommendation Tool"; // Text at top of output
        double maxPerformanceScore = 0 , minPerformanceScore = 0; // holds the highest and lowest performance scores from inputs  

               
                
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);// Create a Scanner object to get the user's input

  
        System.out.print("How many computers are being processed? "); //first question in output
        numOfComputers = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(toolname);
        
        // Validates user input
        while(numOfComputers < 1)//While the user provides us with invalid input, we want to display an error message and have them re-enter their input
        {
            System.out.print("You must enter a number more than 0.  How many computers are being processed? ");//ask the user to enter the number of memberships
            numOfComputers = keyboard.nextInt();//read in the user's input for the number of memberships
        }
                
      //Use for loop to ask the user to enter the information for each membership
      for(int computerNumber = 0; computerNumber < numOfComputers; computerNumber++)
      {

         // Menu Display
         System.out.print("\nPlease enter the clock speed (in Megahertz) of your graphics card: ");
         GPU = keyboard.nextInt(); // Users input for question regarding gpu
      
            while(GPU < 800 || GPU > 2000)
            {
               System.out.print("Invalid selection.  Please pick a value between 800 and 2000: ");//display an error message if the user gave us invalid input
               GPU = keyboard.nextInt();//read in the user's input for the menu selection
            }

           System.out.print("Please enter the clock speed (in Megahertz) of your processor: ");
           CPU = keyboard.nextInt(); // Users input for question regarding cpu
      
            while(CPU < 1000 || CPU > 5500)
            {
               System.out.print("Invalid selection.  Please pick a value between 1000 and 5500: ");//display an error message if the user gave us invalid input
               CPU = keyboard.nextInt();//read in the user's input for the menu selection
            }

           System.out.print("Please enter the number of cores of your processor: ");
           coreCPU = keyboard.nextInt(); // Users input for number of cores in cpu

            while(coreCPU < 1 || coreCPU > 16)
            {
               System.out.print("Invalid selection.  Please pick a value between 1 and 16: ");//display an error message if the user gave us invalid input
               coreCPU = keyboard.nextInt();//read in the user's input for the menu selection
            }
        
              // Menu regarding monitor resolution
              System.out.println("What is the resolution of your monitor?");
              System.out.println("\t1. 1280 x 720");
              System.out.println("\t2. 1920 x 1080");
              System.out.println("\t3. 2560 x 1440");
              System.out.println("\t4. 3840 x 2160");
              System.out.print("Please select from the options above: ");
              choice = keyboard.nextInt(); // user input to question

           while(choice < 1 || choice > 4)//While the user provides us with invalid input, we want to display an error message and have them re-enter their input
            {
               System.out.print("Invalid selection.  Please pick a valid option from the menu: ");//display an error message if the user gave us invalid input
               choice = keyboard.nextInt();//read in the user's input for the menu selection
            }     
            
            // Printing output
            System.out.println("\nGPU Clock Speed: "+GPU);
            System.out.println("CPU Clock Speed: "+CPU);
            System.out.println("Number of cores: "+coreCPU);
            System.out.println("Monitor Resolution: "+ monitorRes);
            System.out.printf("Performance Score: %,.3f\n", performanceScore);
            System.out.println("Recommended Graphics Quality: "+ graphicQuality);
     
            // performance scores
            if(performanceScore > maxPerformanceScore || maxPerformanceScore==0)
             maxPerformanceScore = performanceScore;
            if(performanceScore < minPerformanceScore || minPerformanceScore==0)
               minPerformanceScore = performanceScore;
     }  // end loop    
      
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.printf("The highest performance score was: %,.3f ", maxPerformanceScore);
      System.out.printf("\nThe lowest performance score was: %,.3f ", minPerformanceScore);
                 
   } // end main
 
   /**
      displayTitle method prints out toolname to top of output
      @toolname the text “Computer Hardware Graphics Quality Recommendation Tool” and displays it 
      @return A reference to a String object containing the first and last names.    
   */
   public static String displayTitle(String toolname)
   {
      String name;
      name = toolname;
      return name;
      
   } // end fullName method
   
  /**
      Denotes the monitor resolution       
      @param resType The resolution type (1 is 720, 2 is 1080, 3 is 1440, and 4 is 2160)
      @param choice The users choice
      @return The monitor resolution  
  */
 
 public static String getResolutionString(int resType, String monitorRes)
 {

        // final values for resolution
        final int RESOLUTION_720P = 1;
        final int RESOLUTION_1080P = 2;
        final int RESOLUTION_1440P = 3;
        final int RESOLUTION_2160P = 4;
  
   
      double multiplier = 0.0;
        // Assigns menu options to proper values
                if(resType == RESOLUTION_720P)
                {
                  multiplier = 1;
                  monitorRes = "1280 x 720";
                }
                else if(resType == RESOLUTION_1080P)
               {
                  multiplier = 0.75;
                  monitorRes ="1920 x 1080";
               }
               else if(resType == RESOLUTION_1440P)
               {
                  multiplier = 0.55;
                  monitorRes = "2560 x 1440";
               }
               else if(resType == RESOLUTION_2160P)
               {
                  multiplier= 0.35;
                  monitorRes = "3840 x 2160";    
               }
               
            return monitorRes;  

} // end of getResolutionString method

/**
      Denotes the monitor resolution and returns multiplier value       
      @param resType The resolution type (1 is 720, 2 is 1080, 3 is 1440, and 4 is 2160)
      @param multiplier the multipler value
      @return returns the appropriate multiplier value
  
*/

public static double getMultiplierValue(int resType, double multiplier)
{
 // final values for resolution
        final int RESOLUTION_720P = 1;
        final int RESOLUTION_1080P = 2;
        final int RESOLUTION_1440P = 3;
        final int RESOLUTION_2160P = 4;
  
   
        String monitorRes = ""; // Holds resolutions for monitors  
        // Assigns menu options to proper values
                if(resType == RESOLUTION_720P)
                {
                  multiplier = 1;
                  monitorRes = "1280 x 720";
                }
                else if(resType == RESOLUTION_1080P)
               {
                  multiplier = 0.75;
                  monitorRes ="1920 x 1080";
               }
               else if(resType == RESOLUTION_1440P)
               {
                  multiplier = 0.55;
                  monitorRes = "2560 x 1440";
               }
               else if(resType == RESOLUTION_2160P)
               {
                  multiplier= 0.35;
                  monitorRes = "3840 x 2160";    
               }
               
            return multiplier;
} // end getMultiplerValue method 

/**
      Calculates and returns performance score       
      @param GPU megahertz of gpu
      @param CPU megaherts of cpu
      @param coreCPU number of cores in cpu
      @param multiplier The multiplier value
      @return returns the performance score
  
*/

public static double calculatePerformanceScore(int GPU, int CPU, int coreCPU, double multiplier)
{

double performanceScore = 0; // score used to determine whether your computer can handle a game

 // Calculating Performance Score
         performanceScore = ((5 * GPU) + (coreCPU * CPU)) * multiplier;
         return performanceScore;

} // end of calculatePerformanceScore method
   
/**
      Accepts performance score and returns a recommended graphics quality       
      @param performanceScore     
      @param graphicsQuality
      @return returns the recommended graphics quality  
*/
 
public static String getRecommendedQuality(double performanceScore, String graphicQuality)
{
     
 // Graphics Quality
            if(performanceScore>17000)
               graphicQuality="Ultra";
            else if(performanceScore>15000 && performanceScore<=17000)
               graphicQuality="High";
            else if(performanceScore>13000 && performanceScore<=15000)
               graphicQuality="Medium";
            else if(performanceScore>11000 && performanceScore<=13000)
               graphicQuality="Low";
            else if(performanceScore<=11000)
               graphicQuality="Unable to Play";

   return graphicQuality;

} // end of getRecommendedQuality method

/**
      Accepts performance score and returns a recommended graphics quality       
      @param GPU     
      @param CPU
      @param coreCPU
      @param monitorRes
      @param performanceScore
      @param graphicsQuality
      
*/
public static void displayInformation(int GPU, int CPU, int coreCPU, String monitorRes, double performanceScore, String graphicQuality)
{
     System.out.println("\nGPU Clock Speed: "+GPU);
     System.out.println("CPU Clock Speed: "+CPU);
     System.out.println("Number of cores: "+coreCPU);
     System.out.println("Monitor Resolution: "+ monitorRes);
     System.out.printf("Performance Score: %,.3f\n", performanceScore);
     System.out.println("Recommended Graphics Quality: "+ graphicQuality);
}
 
 
 
 
 
 

} // end class
```

Comment: It would better to help when you specify what part of code or variables have issue/unexpected values.

Comment: an example with expected output and actual output that's been printed would help a lot to find your problem